# CSS calc() for inverse width isn't working

Tags: css, responsive, css-calc

I have an element that I want to increase in `width` as its parent decreases in `width`

The equation should look something like:

```css
width:calc(150 + 500 / 100%);
```

But at least in Chrome it says the property is invalid whenever I try to divide by percent width.

Is this possible? (Alternatives to `calc()` are acceptable)

**EDIT**
I added spaces (didn't realize about that). Tried it with a variety of units, no luck yet.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rq7txzd/)

```
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;">
    <div style="width:calc(150px + (500 / 100%));position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">This one should get bigger as the page gets smaller</div>
</div>
```

Thought process:

Fixed width (150px) plus 500 divided by the current parent width.

So if the parent is 500px:

150 + 500/500 -> 150 + 1 = 151

Parent is 100px

150 + 500/100 -> 150 + 5 = 155

Parent is 20px

150 + 500/20 -> 150 + 100 = 250

Comment: Take the % symbol out of the calc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is so simple it's mind-boggling. Move the 500px into the first part and subtract the width.

```
width:calc(650px - 100%);
```

Gets wider as its parent gets narrower.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rq7txzd/2/)

Answer (score 3):

`calc()` need spaces between the operators ( but just in `+` and `-`), but you are missing the units, which could be `px`, `em`,`rem` etc..., so would something like this:

```css
width:calc(150px + (500px / 100%))
```

This is would be invalid because as explained by @TylerH, you can't divide by un-ed values(`px`, `%`, etc).

But if was possible, when you divide by 100% you are multiplying by 1, so basically you'll stay the same because 1 is the neutral value for multiplication, so this would be useless to do.

---

Hardly to know, because there isn't much to see in your question, and still invalid, but I'm guessing you are looking for something like this instead:

```css
width:calc(150px + (100% / 500px))
```

---

Given your Edited question AFAIK you have to use JS to achieve this, unless you could provide a Fiddle.

Comment: By the way, only `+` and `-` require space. The `*` and `/` operators don't require space around them. [Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-syntax)

Comment: I upvoted your comment, I always forget that, I got used to spacing between all the operators, thanks for the reminder. I'm going to update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you've found your solution already, but I'll answer specifically *why* your original code wasn't working:

I'll start with the syntax for a product equation (when you divide) in calc():

> `<calc-product>` = `<calc-value>` [ '`*`' `<calc-value>` | '`/`' `<number>` ]

The [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-syntax) for the calc() property syntax is a bit more complicated than it sounds. When dividing in calc() as you're doing here, the right side must be a [**number**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#number-value). You cannot use "unit-ed" values:

> Number values are denoted by `<number>`, and represent real numbers, possibly with a fractional component.
>
> When written literally, a number is either an integer, or zero or more decimal digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more decimal digits and optionally an exponent composed of "e" or "E" and an integer. It corresponds to the  production in the [CSS Syntax Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax/). As with integers, the first character of a number may be immediately preceded by - or + to indicate the number’s sign.

That is to say, you cannot divide something *by* a percentage value like 100%.